# Unable to download pdfs in my angular application

Tags: angular, api, frontend

I've a flask get api that downloads a zip file whenever the api is hit.

```
api - https://example.com/downloads/user1
```

In my angular application, I have put a download button that calls a service.

download.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class downloadService extends BaseService {

protected modelUrl: string = 'downloads';

constructor(protected http: Http, protected _router: Router, protected _authService: AuthService) {
super(http, _router, _authService);
}

fetchDownloadUrl(body:any): Observable<Result> {
  return this.get(this.getUrl() + "/downloads/" + body);
} 
}
```

In my download.component.ts

```
function () {
    
    self.downloadService.fetchDownloadUrl(user).subscribe(
      response => {
        swal({
          position: "center",
          title: "Downloaded!",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1500,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
      }
```

When I click the button, it should hit the api in the service. But I'm getting the pdf as response, instead of getting downloaded in my local machine.

Also when I hit the url in my chrome directly, I could able to download.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

First in fetchDownloadUrl, add httpOptions responseType.

download.service.ts

```
fetchDownloadUrl(body:any): Observable<Result> {
   const httpOptions = {
      'responseType'  : 'blob' as 'json'
    };

  return this.get(this.getUrl() + "/downloads/" + body, httpOptions);
}
```

download.component.ts

```
function () {
    
    self.downloadService.fetchDownloadUrl(user).subscribe(
      response => {
      downloadPdfFile(response)
        swal({
          position: "center",
          title: "Downloaded!",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1500,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
      }
      
      
downloadPdfFile(data : any) {
    console.log(data)
    let file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  }
```

Somewhere in your html file

```
<button (click)="download();">Download</button>
```